# possible reasons why C program malloc assignment returns NULL?

Tags: c

I'm using gcc4.4.4 and gdb on 64bit Linux centos 5.7, compiling to ansi C. I'm not sure why my code tests true for PDF == NULL below, and calls exit(2).

```
void func(...)
...
double *PDF;
...
PDF = malloc( sizeof(double) * 1 );
if (PDF == NULL) {
    exit(2); 
}
```

Using free -m, I observe before the program starts:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2001       1955         46          0         71        975
-/+ buffers/cache:        907       1094
Swap:         4008        688       3319
```

and when the program sits on the exit(2); line of code, free -m reads:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2001       1970         31          0         72        976
-/+ buffers/cache:        921       1080
Swap:         4008        688       3319
```

In both cases, there's plenty of memory available in the cache row, free column (certainly enough for one byte).

What are other possible reasons PDF would become NULL? What coding bugs could cause this?

In case it matters, I've been using gdb a lot in the last week, exiting the program using "q" then "y" instead of letting it complete (figuring all malloc memory would be freed by the program terminating thus not needing to execute the free() code).

Comment: Can we see a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) sample (`main()`, includes, and gcc flags) that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've written beyond the bounds of a buffer somewhere, you may have corrupted the heap, in which case all bets are off.

I suggest using e.g. Valgrind to check that you haven't done something like this.

Comment: Doesn't even work for allocating one byte (updated question above).

Comment: @ggkmath: Doesn't matter; if the heap is corrupted then the heap is corrupted.

Comment: Indeed, all the more reason to believe the heap is corrupted.

Comment: I am doing a lot with the heap before this point, so this is possibly the cause. Is there any good way to debug this using gdb?

Comment: @ggkmath: It would be far easier to use a proper memory debugger, such as Valgrind.  It's designed to diagnose exactly this sort of problem.

Comment: OK, I made a couple trivial (unrelated) changes that somehow caused the compiler to find a couple missing semicolons on exit(2) lines of code similar to above. After putting in these semicolons I'm no longer having malloc troubles. Seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` returns NULL when the calling process cannot allocate anymore memory, perhaps because a [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) system call fails because you reached some limits, like those set by [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)

An individual process can reach its limit even if some memory is available to other processes.

You can use `strace` to trace the system calls and find out which one is failing.

And be sure to compile with `gcc -Wall -g` (and use the debugger `gdb`).